# Positivity of $a + \lambda b$ implies what?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $a, b$ be elements of a unital C*-algebra with unit $1$, $b = b^*$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. If $b$ is not an element of the operator system generated by $\{1, a\}$ and $a + \lambda b = p + q$, where $p$ is positive and $q = q^*$, then should $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$?

Answer (score 1):

No. We denote the unit in a $C^*$- algebra by $e$. Then take $a=ie$ and $b=e$ and $ \lambda=1-i.$ Then

$$a+ \lambda b = ie+(1-i)e=e.$$

Thus $a+ \lambda b$ is positive , but $\lambda \ne  \overline{\lambda}.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer to the original question. I have now modified the original question by including a few more hypotheses.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one can conclude at the least, $a = a^*$ and $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$ from just assuming that $a + \lambda b$ is self-adjoint, as follows. Have $a + \lambda b = a^* + \overline{\lambda}b$. If $\overline{\lambda} \neq \lambda$, then $b = \frac{1}{\overline{\lambda} - \lambda}(a - a^*)$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $b$ does not belong to the operator system generated by $\{1, a\}$.Thus $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$, which in turn implies that  $a = a^*$. Can anything more be concluded?